# Word for that speedy, agile class of fantasy heroes (rangers, ninjas, thieves, etc)

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If knights/warriors are STRONG and wear armor, wizards/mages are INTELLIGENT and cast magic, then what do you call that class of fantasy heroes defined by their SPEED? (Rangers, monks, assassins, ninjas, thieves, swashbucklers, etc.)

In video games, they're often called "agility heroes", or defined as "leather armor wearers."

The best I could come up with is "specialists," but it's too vague. "Commandos" is too modern-military. "Ranger" is too specific: in fantasy contexts it means a Legolas-type. "Speed freak" is the only technically correct term, but it's ridiculous. "Athlete" invokes sports images. "Runner" invokes 80s sci-fi movies.

I'm tempted to just call them "agiles", but I'm afraid it's too weak. ("The knights and agiles leered at each other from across the bar." "While the knight battled the skeleton, the agile dashed for the crystal.")

Maybe there's a good foreign-language word...?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "Dexterity class" comes close, but obviously not a single word. How about zero-nominalizing *swift*? "The knights and *swifts* leered at each other from across the bar."

Comment: "Fleet-footed" class may do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The term that is most inclusive of all the "heroes" you mentioned (except maybe monks) is rogue[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)). The Wikipedia entry for rogues in *Dungeons and Dragons* describes a member of this character class as "a versatile character, capable of sneaky combat and nimble tricks. The rogue is sneaky and dexterous..."

That same article mentions thieves, bards, swashbucklers, and assassins as members of the rogue class in the various editions of *Dungeons & Dragons*.

> The knights and **rogues** leered at each other from across the bar.

Answer (score 0):

"Scout" has the right ring to it but the meaning might be a little bit specific for how many different professions you want to include in it.

Answer (score 0):

Although I do like "rogue", how about "jack" if you're looking for something a little different?

Some examples:

> Jack be nimble,
>
> Jack be quick,
>
> Jack jump over the candlestick.

Jack-of-all-trades, Jack the Giant-Killer, jackanapes...